# Spring MVC, no data showing in my index.jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, model-view-controller

I am practicing to create my own JDBC CRUD web app by studying online... However, when I tried to test it, no data is being shown in my index.jsp and I cannot locate the error in my code. I checked/reworked my code over and over, looked at the console for any errors but still nothing happens. It made me hesitate to continue coding for the remaining CRUD ops.

I am having a hard time because I think that I properly passed the listBooks object in the jsp to the servlet, or have I not?

Here is my Controller Servlet:

```
 @WebServlet("/BookServlet")
public class BookServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private BookDAO bkDAO;
    
    public void init() {
        String jdbcURL = getServletContext().getInitParameter("jdbcURL");
        String jdbcUsername = getServletContext().getInitParameter("jdbcUsername");
        String jdbcPassword = getServletContext().getInitParameter("jdbcPassword");
        
        bkDAO = new BookDAO(jdbcURL, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword);
    }
   
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = request.getServletPath();
        
        try {
            switch(action) {
            case "/new":
                showNewForm(request, response);
                break;
            case "/insert":
                insertBook(request, response);
                break;
            case "/delete":
                break;
            case "/edit":
                break;
            case "/update":
                break;
                
            default:
                bookcollection(request, response);
                break;
            }
            
        }catch(SQLException e) {
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
        
        
    }
    
    private void bookcollection(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws SQLException, IOException, ServletException{
            //list object from the Data Access Object
            List<BookCollectionModel> listBooks = bkDAO.listBooks();
            request.setAttribute("listBooks", listBooks);
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
    
    private void showNewForm (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws SQLException, IOException, ServletException{
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("BookForm.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
    
    private void insertBook (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws SQLException, IOException, ServletException{
        int bookID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("bookID"));
        String title  = request.getParameter("title");
        String author = request.getParameter("author");
        String publisher = request.getParameter("publisher");
        String edition = request.getParameter("edition");
        int pages = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pages"));
        int year = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("year"));
        int price = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("price"));
        
        BookCollectionModel newBook = new BookCollectionModel(bookID, title, author, publisher, edition, pages, year, price);
        bkDAO.insertBook(newBook);
        
        response.sendRedirect("list");
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

My Data Access Object Code:

```
public class BookDAO {
    
    private String jdbcURL;
    private String jdbcUsername;
    private String jdbcPassword;
    private Connection jdbcConnection;
    
    public BookDAO(String jdbcURL, String jdbcUsername, String jdbcPassword) {
        this.jdbcURL = jdbcURL;
        this.jdbcUsername = jdbcUsername;
        this.jdbcPassword = jdbcPassword;
    }
    
    protected void connect() throws SQLException{
        if(jdbcConnection == null || jdbcConnection.isClosed()) {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new SQLException(e);
            }
            jdbcConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword);
        }
    }
    protected void disconnect() throws SQLException{
        if(jdbcConnection != null && jdbcConnection.isClosed()) {
            jdbcConnection.close();
        }
    }
    public List<BookCollectionModel> listBooks() throws SQLException{
        List<BookCollectionModel> listBooks = new ArrayList<>();
    
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM bookinformation ORDER BY title";    
    

    //create statement for connection
    Statement statement = jdbcConnection.createStatement();
    //result set contains the records retrieved on executing the SQL.
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
    
    //looping all the records on the result set
    while(resultSet.next()) {
        int id = resultSet.getInt("bookID");
        String title = resultSet.getString("title");
        String author = resultSet.getString("author");
        String publisher = resultSet.getString("publisher");
        String edition = resultSet.getString("edition");
        int pages = resultSet.getInt("pages");
        int year = resultSet.getInt("year");
        int price = resultSet.getInt("price");
        
        BookCollectionModel books = new BookCollectionModel(id, title, author, publisher, edition, pages, year, price);
        listBooks.add(books);
    }
    resultSet.close();
    statement.close();
    disconnect();
    return listBooks;
    }
    
    public boolean insertBook (BookCollectionModel newBook) throws SQLException{
        String sql = "INSERT INTO bookinformation (bookID, title, author, publisher, edition, pages, year, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        connect();
        
        PreparedStatement statement = jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setInt(1, newBook.getBookID());
        statement.setString(2, newBook.getTitle());
        statement.setString(3, newBook.getAuthor());
        statement.setString(4, newBook.getPublisher());
        statement.setString(5, newBook.getEdition());
        statement.setInt(6, newBook.getPages());
        statement.setInt(7, newBook.getYear());
        statement.setInt(8, newBook.getPrice());
        
        boolean rowInserted = statement.executeUpdate() > 0;
        statement.close();
        disconnect();
        return rowInserted;
    }
}
```

Here is my index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Book Collection DB</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Book Management</h1>
        <h2>
            <a href="/BookCollectionJDBC/new">Add New Account</a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="/BookCollectionJDBC/list">List All Accounts</a>
        </h2>
        
    <div align="center">
        <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
            <caption><h2>List of Books</h2>
            <tr>
                <th>Book ID</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Publisher</th>
                <th>Edition</th>
                <th>Pages</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        <c:forEach var="books" items="${listBooks}">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${books.bookID}"></c:out></td>
                <td><c:out value="${books.title}"></c:out></td>
                <td><c:out value="${books.author}"></c:out></td>
                <td><c:out value="${books.publisher}"></c:out></td>
                <td><c:out value="${books.edition}"></c:out></td>
                <td><c:out value="${books.pages}"></c:out></td>
                <td><c:out value="${books.year}"></c:out></td>
                <td><c:out value="${books.price}"></c:out></td>
                
                <td>
                    <a href="/BookCollectionJDBC/edit?id=<c:out value='${books.bookID}'/>">Edit</a>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="/BookCollectionJDBC/delete?id=<c:out value='${books.bookID}'/>">Delete</a>
                
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>        
        </table>
    
    </div>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" version="4.0">
  <display-name>BookCollectionJDBC</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
   <context-param>
    <param-name>jdbcURL</param-name>
    <param-value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookcollectiondb</param-value>
  </context-param>
  
  <context-param>
    <param-name>jdbcUsername</param-name>
    <param-value>root</param-value>
  </context-param>
  
  <context-param>
    <param-name>jdbcPassword</param-name>
    <param-value>123456</param-value>
  </context-param>  
  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>BookServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.model.BookServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BookServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to review programming again with this code...

Code was fine as kameshrsr said. I just missed to call connect() in my Data Access Object Code.

This was my code before:

```
 public List<BookCollectionModel> listBooks() throws SQLException{
            List<BookCollectionModel> listBooks = new ArrayList<>();
    
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM bookinformation ORDER BY title";    
    

    //create statement for connection
    Statement statement = jdbcConnection.createStatement();
    //result set contains the records retrieved on executing the SQL.
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

It should be:

```
public List<BookCollectionModel> listBooks() throws SQLException{
                List<BookCollectionModel> listBooks = new ArrayList<>();
    
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM bookinformation ORDER BY title";    
        
    connect();   //I missed this part

    //create statement for connection
    Statement statement = jdbcConnection.createStatement();
    //result set contains the records retrieved on executing the SQL.
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Can you check your database in MySQL workbench whether data is stored or not or you can manually put one record in one of your tables and check whether data is successfully retrieving on your JSP page or not?

Comment: There are data in the database which I manually entered in MySQL workbench. However, data is not successfully retrieving on my JSP page. I posted this because maybe I have missed something in the passing of data between my servlet and jsp.

Comment: Your data is successfully saving in the database from your JSP page?

Comment: No, apparently after entering data in the form it shows an HTTP error 500 with time zone when I click submit button. 

java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Malay Peninsula Standard Time' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

Comment: I apparently solved this problem on the time zone error and data is now successfully saving in the database from my JSP page and records from the database are successfully shown in the JSP Page. However, when restarting the web app, it does not automatically display the data in the JSP Page... I need to add another record just for it to refresh and show all the data in the database. Sorry, I am quite confused on this.